# Choose Items from a List in multithreaded python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am a beginner in python and cant figure out how to do this:
I am running a python script that puts a new value every 5-10 seconds into a list. I want to choose these elements from the list in another multithreaded python script however per thread one value, so one value shouldnt be reused, if theres no next value, then wait until next value is present. I have some code where I tried to do it but with no success:

Script that creates values:

```
values = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
cap = []

while True:
    cap.append(random.choice(values))
    print cap
    time.sleep(5)
```

Script that needs these values:

```
def adding(self):

p = cap.pop()
print (p)
```

However in a multithreaded environment, each thread gives me the same value, even thought I want value for each thread to be different (e.g remove value already used by thread) What are my options here?

Comment: `cap.append(random.choice(values))` do you mean `cap.extend(random.choice(values))` ? what is your expected output and what's your current input?

Comment: What's wrong with `append`? Isn't the goal just grabbing a random string from values and plugging it into cap?

Comment: I'd recommend checking out multiprocessing instead of threading. Threading in python runs into the Global Interpreter Lock, which means it's often not what you want to be using.

Comment: @dashiell if you know what OP means, well, good for you. I don't.

Comment: Using `cap.pop()` should be thread-safe (as long as it's just one thread doing the populating). Are you sure you're using threads, not forked processes? Please provide a *complete* [MCVE], or we can't really help.

Comment: @dashiell: `multiprocessing` has its own major pitfalls (e.g. my suspicion that they're already using it, causing this problem), and threading has a place in a situation where most threads are spending time doing work in C extensions or blocked on I/O, queues, etc. Yes, the GIL makes threading unsuitable for CPU bound work at the Python level, but that doesn't make it useless.

Comment: @ShadowRanger fair enough, though I suspect that OP isn't using either threads or processes, and might just be running each script side by side.

Comment: The random number generator will generate values based upon the the random number seed. This is often generated from the system clock. In multithreaded system, they may all share the same seed. You need to change the seed somehow in each thread. See if creating a global variable, and then adding 1 to it before a call to `random.seed(globalVariable)` helps.

Comment: Well I think I explained badly, sorry about that. What I want is to transfer values from scriptA (which puts values into lists) into scriptB which uses these values to fulfil http request payloads. My issue is that I am using multiprocessing threading in scriptB however I am unable to transfer values from scriptA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to use one thread (a producer) to fill a list with values, and then a few different threads (consumers) to remove from that same list. Thus resulting with a series of consumers which have mutually exclusive subsets of the values added by the producer.

A possible outcome might be:

**Producer**

```
cap.append('a')
cap.append('c')
cap.append('b')
cap.append('f')
```

**Consumer 1**

```
cap.pop() # a
cap.pop() # f
```

**Consumer 2**

```
cap.pop() # c
cap.pop() # b
```

If this is the behavior you want I recommend using a thread-safe object like a [Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136890/choose-items-from-a-list-in-multithreaded-python) (python 2.*) or [queue](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/queue.html) (python 3.*)

Here is one possible implementation

**Producer**

```
import Queue
values = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
q = Queue.Queue()

while True:
    q.put(random.choice(values))
    print q
    time.sleep(5)
```

**Consumer**

```
val = q.get() # this call will block (aka wait) for something to be available
print(val)
```

Its also very important that both the producer and the consumer have access to the same instance of the of `q`.

Comment: upvoted, same problem unfortunately q doesnt seem like an option because i have to loop through all the items meaning producer keeps adding items to the list, consumer loops through items,checks their status, if status ready pops only those from the list, any recommendations for this are appreciated